# Internet from docker container with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, proxy, kubernetes

I setup `cntlm` as a proxy of my enterprise proxy with the good credentials.
It binds on all interface.

It works fine in local with environment variable export

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

In a standalone docker environment, I setup the `http_proxy` with `http://172.17.0.1:3128` (which is the ip of `docker0`). It works as well.

Now I did the same configuration with a kubernetes cluster. And it seems to not work properly. I did a telnet and I am not able to contact `cntlm` which is installed on the host.

Any idea of what's wrong?

Regards.

Comment: In forgot to specify that I would like to contact cntlm on the host from a docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to contact cntlm on the host from a docker container

There are many ways to make a kubernetes pod communicate with an application on the host outside docker / kubernetes:

1. Use `hostNetwork: true` and communicate with `cntlm` on the host from inside the pod:

   ```
   kind: Pod
   spec:
     template:
       spec:
         hostNetwork: true
   ```
2. Use [kubernetes port-forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) and forward the `cntlm` port on the host to a free port inside the pod and access `cntlm` (on the host) from inside the pod:

   ```
   kubectl port-forward <pod name> <cntlm's port on host>:<free port in pod>
   ```

   Keep in mind that `kubectl port-forward` does not support forwarding to a service currently due to [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15180).
3. **I recommend this**: Containerize `cntlm` too and deploy it in kubernetes and communicate with it using [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) in k8s.